# Powershell dynamic <tab> completion

Tags: git, powershell

> ^ before voting to close, understand that the "answer" to the above question is to use another module, not how to implement it yourself.

I have a set of powershell modules that I use to help me with my git workflow (think [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow)).

Here's an example.

```
Function Merge-FromBranch([string] $branch){
    # ...
}

Set-Alias mfb Merge-FromBranch
```

I would like to be able to have tab completion for the branch name using branches that exist in the repo.

Now getting the local branch names is easy

```
> git branch
```

but what I need to be able to do is

```
> mfb fea<tab>
```

in order to tab through the feature branches.

How can I wire it up so that I can tab complete the `$branch` parameter on my module?

I know I can pipe the `git branch` output to another method (`git branch | do-stuff`), but I don't know how to integrate it into tab completion of a module.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) or am I misunderstanding your needs?

Comment: we use posh-git as well, but our custom commands add even more additional functionality.

Comment: if the set of branches is static you could use ValidateSet() in your parameter definition, if i remember correctly it should give you tab completion. But i dont know if it would be possible to create the set on the fly if you want to have it dynamic. edit: maybe this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844542/powershell-cmdlet-parameter-value-tab-completion

Comment: posh-git does it via the [TabExpansions](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/master/GitTabExpansion.ps1). I'm just trying to adapt it to my needs now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In keeping with how posh-git has done it, and making my own `TabExpansion` method, I now have proper tab completion for my custom commands.

```posh
# Backup the existing TabExpansion, this will allow us to extend it rather than replace it.
Copy Function:\TabExpansion Function:\OriginalTabExpansion

# Create our own custom TabExpansion method
function TabExpansion($line, $lastWord) {
  $LineBlocks = [regex]::Split($line, '[|;]')
  $lastBlock = $LineBlocks[-1] 

  switch -regex ($lastBlock) {
    #Depends on Posh-Git
    "^$(Get-AliasPattern "mfb|mtb|rb|db|ub|urb|co|pull") (.*)" { gitTabExpansion $lastBlock }
    default { if (Test-Path Function:\OriginalTabExpansion) { OriginalTabExpansion $line $lastWord } }
  }
}

function gitTabExpansion($lastBlock) {
     switch -regex ($lastBlock) {
        "(?<cmd>\S*)$" { gitBranches $matches['cmd'] $true }
    }   
}

function script:gitBranches($filter, $includeHEAD = $false) {
    $prefix = $null
    if ($filter -match "^(?<from>\S*\.{2,3})(?<to>.*)") {
        $prefix = $matches['from']
        $filter = $matches['to']
    }
    $branches = @(git branch --no-color | foreach { if($_ -match "^\*?\s*(?<ref>.*)") { $matches['ref'] } }) +
                @(git branch --no-color -r | foreach { if($_ -match "^  (?<ref>\S+)(?: -> .+)?") { $matches['ref'] } }) +
                @(if ($includeHEAD) { 'HEAD','FETCH_HEAD','ORIG_HEAD','MERGE_HEAD' })
    $branches |
        where { $_ -ne '(no branch)' -and $_ -like "$filter*" } |
        foreach { $prefix + $_ }
}
```

Comment: That one is really great! I have one question though: When putting it into my custom functions file it doesn't seem to know Function:\TabExpansion. For that i decided to put it on the end of posh-git's GitTabExpansion.ps1. I cannot imagine that this is the right way to do this, so if you have an answer for that as well it would be great :)

Comment: @x_mtd you're right in that it's not the right way. You want it to be in the module that you import. [Here's the import](https://github.com/FutureStateMobile/fsm-posh/blob/master/src/profile.fsm-git/FsmGit.psm1#L45) how we do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `git branch` and what it outputs. I expect it to only be branch-names, one value per line without any header etc. If not, then you need to modify the sample to clean it first.

This should work for PS3+ if I believe:

```
function Merge-FromBranch {

[CmdletBinding()]
Param() 

    DynamicParam {
            # Set the dynamic parameters' name
            $ParameterName = 'Branch'

            # Create the dictionary 
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

            # Create the collection of attributes
            $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

            # Create and set the parameters' attributes
            $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
            $ParameterAttribute.Position = 1

            # Add the attributes to the attributes collection
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

            # Generate and set the ValidateSet 
            $arrSet = & git branch
            $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)

            # Add the ValidateSet to the attributes collection
            $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

            # Create and return the dynamic parameter
            $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
            $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
            return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }

    begin {
        # Bind the parameter to a friendly variable
        $Branch = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
    }

    process { Write-Host "Chosen Branch is: $Branch" }

}
```

Sample modified from: [Dynamic ValidateSet in a Dynamic Parameter @ blogs.technet.com](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pstips/archive/2014/06/10/dynamic-validateset-in-a-dynamic-parameter.aspx)

Comment: DynamicParam was something that I looked into, but it sure makes for a lot of bloated modules. After quite a lot of digging, I came up with the `TabExpansion` stuff that's baked into Powershell. I basically ripped off what was already being done in posh-git

Comment: Okey. :) As long as you don't have 100s of these parameters I wouldn't consider them very bloated, but that's just my opinion. To keep the module clean in PowerShell ISE you can use regions like this `#region DynamicParam - Branch  <newline> this code.... <newline> #endregion`.